# What could cause strange behavior in file(1) command?

Tags: files, mime-types, file-command

What could cause `file(1)` command to output `application/msword application/msword` (yes, twice in a row) as the mime type for *some* of the .doc files?  Normally it prints just `application/msword`.

If run without `--mime` it prints `Microsoft Office Document` on both 'normal' and 'special' .doc files.

Comment: Actually not all of the files are `.doc`, it appears that some of them are `.xls`, for which I get `application/msword` (once) and for `.doc`s I get it twice.

Comment: Strange indeed. What is the exact `file` invocation (with exact file names)? What is the exact `file` version (version number, distribution, …)?

Comment: @Gilles: `file-4.17-15.el5_3.1.x86_64` on CentOS 5.5 Final.  Command line is like this: `file -bi /path/to/file/<md5-like-string>`, where the filename doesn't have any suffix.

Comment: Is it sending both responses on the same stream?

Comment: What does your /usr/share/misc/magic file (or equivalent) look like? What happens when you use the -k option?

Answer (score 3):

From the magic(5) man page:

> Some file formats contain additional information which is to be printed along with  the file  type  or need additional tests to determine the true file type.  These additional tests are introduced by one or more > characters preceding the offset.  The number of >  on  the line indicates the level of the test; a line with no > at the beginning is considered to be at level 0.  Tests are arranged in a tree-like hierarchy: If a  the  test on  a line at level n succeeds, all following tests at level n+1 are performed, and the messages printed if the tests succeed, untile a line with level n  (or  less)  appears. For more complex files, one can use empty messages to get just the "if/then" effect, in  the following way:

```
       0      string   MZ
       >0x18  leshort  <0x40   MS-DOS executable
       >0x18  leshort  >0x3f   extended PC executable (e.g., MS Windows)
```

On our Scientific Linux 5.5 system, `/usr/share/file/magic.mime` lines 836..838 look like this:

```
0       string  \320\317\021\340\241\261\032\341        application/msword
>546    string  bjbj                    application/msword
>546    string  jbjb                    application/msword
```

So, once the first line matches, `file` will check for `bjbj` and `jbjb` at the given location, printing an additional `application/msword` string on success.

Note: if you want to fix that file, you have to remove, rename, or regenerate (with `file -C`) the binary version, `/usr/share/file/magic.mime.mgc`, since `file` prefers that one to the text version.